# Images ( PNG or JPEG ) file size increased when uploaded through wysiwyg editor

Tags: magento-1.9, image, wysiwyg

I have both optimized PNG and JPEG images that I want to upload in wysiwyg but everytime I check it in frontend after upload and save it to my computer, the file size changes to triple of the original file size. I tried changing `imagejpeg($img, $filePath, 100);` to `imagejpeg($img, $filePath);` from mage/core file but nothing happens. How can I solve this?

Comment: can you clear the cache and try

Answer (score 1):

Its because of SUPEE-9767 Patch increasing image sizes,Turn off the image reprocessing.

```
insert into vbstag_mag.core_config_data (scope, scope_id, path, value) values('default','0','general/reprocess_images/active','0')
```

Comment: I have searched the core_config_data tables and can't locate 'general/reprocess_images/active' in the database.  Is this only in the Enterprise version?
Any directions you can offer so I can locate this to turn reprocessing off?